# Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' and `double'

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I'm trying to do a simple math equation, however, when I try to use "*" it throws the error

> error CS0019: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type`System.Collections.Generic.List' and `double'

Code example:

```
public static List<string> items = new List<string> ();
public static List<double> itemsprice = new List<double>();
public static List<double> qu = new List<double>();
int i = 0;
        double price = 0;
        while(i != items.Count){
            price = itemsprice[1];
            ticksales = qu * pricepoint / 2; // Error on this line
            income = income + ticksales * price;

        }
```

Comment: Well, yeah. `qu` is a List of doubles. How do you multiply a list of numbers by a number?

Comment: @Blorgbeard One could ask why it works for [vectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599648(v=vs.110).aspx) than? I see nothing wrong to want to multiple List of numbers by a number in general as it is quite standard operation on vectors. Granted OP is not likely looking for that.  (Indeed I know that multiplication would have to produce new List which is expensive and better be explicit call  rather than `*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is occuring because `qu` is a List of type double and you are trying to multiply it. It seems like what you want to do is `qu[i] * pricepoint/2;`

Also you should increment `i` at the end of your loop or it will run forever.

Comment: Really OP should be using `for` loop...

Answer (score 0):

`qu` is a List. What do you think `list * pricepoint / 2` equals? (we don't know what pricepoint is BTW)

Answer (score 0):

`au` is a List, you have to provide the index of the item you want to access. And also at the end you have to increment the index.

```
ticksales = qu[i] * (pricepoint / 2)
```

and `i++;` at the end.